# How to return processed file to the browser after a background job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, web-applications

I have a Rails app that generates a report after a long task, implemented with a background job.

The user clicks a button that shows a spinner and then triggers that background job.
What I want to do is that when the background job finishes the task, return the created file to the browser.

I was thinking of polling the result, asking if the file was created or not, but I don't think that's really correct.

Another potential issue is if the user closes the page/browser before the job has finished.

Comment: If you want to give the response immediately then background job will not help.

Comment: You can use websockets (or a hosted webservice like pusher) to know if the file has been processed, then redirect in javascript to the download page.

Comment: @soundar: if I don't use a background job, the browser closes the connection after 30 seconds, and therefore an HTTP 502 error is generated. But the task is still running at the server.

Comment: I think a pusher gem (faye is a good one) is the way to go.